# Scritable webservice not working crossdomain

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am using this clientaccesspolicy.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

and trying to access webservice using javascript in my subdomain, but its not working in FF, working fine in IE.
I have also tried using crossdomain.xml file which too works fine in IE, but not in FF.

Answer (score 0):

2 monthes

1 jquery ajax jsoncallback
2 create a webservice in your subdomain access the another webservice in other domain, then use your javascript access your new webservice